beta.pair.abund function of "betapart" package return Error in as(x, "matrix")[i, j, drop = FALSE] : (subscript) logical subscript too long
I'm trying to partition the beta diversity of a phyloseq object.
With presence absence it is working on beta.pair but when I'm launching beta.pair.abund I get this message Error in as(x, "matrix")[i, j, drop = FALSE] : (subscript) logical subscript too long.
I tried with a subsample of my community matrix and it is working.
Can you help me with this error?
community_data <- as.matrix(t(otu_table(ENR_ab)))
beta_ms <- beta.pair.abund(community_data, index.family = "bray")

community_data is a matrix where the rows are sites and columns are OTU species.
